# How to declare and call a native method containing pointers in java

Tags: java, android

How to declare and call a native method in c containing pointers using java?
please it is urgent.Because there is no concept of pointers in java i am getting error.

Comment: refer this link. http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/javatutorial/native/implementing/objects.html

Answer (score 1):

Use JNI(Java Native Interfaces) to call native methods in java. Use this JNI specification pdf as a reference "java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf".

Answer (score 0):

There is even a easier approach to the subject, if you or your boss are willing to pay 50$!

Is called [eXcelsior xFunction](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/xfunction.html). Try the evaluation version.

Works very well and is simple to use.

The only thing xFunction library does not do have is implementation of address arithmetic in Java, which i assume you will possibly never need.

From their site:

With xFunction, you no longer need to implement those ugly native methods. Instead, you extend and instantiate xFunction classes to create conventional Java objects representing **external functions**, **data structures**, **pointers**, and **callbacks**. All necessary data conversions and external function calls are done seamlessly by the xFunction library:

```
import com.excelsior.xFunction.*;
...
/* Call Beep() from KERNEL32.DLL */
xFunction f = 
  new xFunction( "kernel32",
                 "int Beep(int,int)" );
f.invoke( new Argument(1770), 
          new Argument(100) );
```